# Definition of spearmanr

Tags: python, statistics

To test my understanding on spearmanr and pearsonr, I compared two ways to compute spearmanr, which should give the same result. Surprisingly, the results are different.

```
import torch
from scipy.stats import pearsonr, spearmanr

x = torch.normal(1, 1, (10,))
y = torch.normal(1, 1, (10,))
_, x_rank = x.sort()
_, y_rank = y.sort()

print(
    spearmanr(x, y),
    pearsonr(x_rank, y_rank)
)
```

To reproduce the results, please use the following `x` and `y`. This should give a pearsonr of rank of `0.263` and spearmanr of `0.139`.

```
x = torch.tensor([ 1.7443, -0.7889,  0.4698,  1.2080,  0.8847, -0.4490,  1.2561,  1.5188,
        -1.0031,  1.4753])
y = torch.tensor([ 1.2675,  1.8317,  1.6912, -0.2964,  2.0014,  1.1092,  2.7958,  2.6034,
        -0.0528, -2.2956])
```

Why are they different? Isn't spearmanr defined as the pearsonr over the rank of `x` and that of `y`? Is there something I missed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Firstly,* just for clarification, [Pearson](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pearson_correlation_coefficient) and [Spearman](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spearman%27s_rank_correlation_coefficient) correlations are not the same, however they can be equal, for eg. in case of perfectly linear relationship. Former is a measure for linear relationship and the later is a measure for monotonic relationship.

*Secondly,* [*tensor sort method*](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.sort.html#torch.sort) does not provide you *rank* but *indices* of your raw data before sorting. what you need is the *indices* of the raw data after sorting but in the order of your raw data *i.e. rank*.

you can do something like:

```
import torch
from scipy.stats import pearsonr, spearmanr

x = torch.tensor([ 1.7443, -0.7889,  0.4698,  1.2080,  0.8847, -0.4490,  1.2561,  1.5188,
        -1.0031,  1.4753])
y = torch.tensor([ 1.2675,  1.8317,  1.6912, -0.2964,  2.0014,  1.1092,  2.7958,  2.6034,
        -0.0528, -2.2956])

x_sorted, x_raw_indx = x.sort()
y_sorted, x_raw_indx = y.sort()

x_ranked = [int((x_sorted == value).nonzero(as_tuple=True)[0]) for value in x]
y_ranked = [int((y_sorted == value).nonzero(as_tuple=True)[0]) for value in y]

spearmanr(x, y) , pearsonr(x_ranked, y_ranked)

#(SpearmanrResult(correlation=0.13939393939393938, pvalue=0.7009318849100584),
# (0.1393939393939394, 0.7009318849100588))
```

As mentioned in comments (@simon), a much cleaner way to get rank is:

```
x_ranked = x.argsort().argsort()
y_ranked = y.argsort().argsort()
```

Comment: I understand the first point but can you write a short code to calculate spearmanr by using `sort` and `pearsonr` functions alone? That should clarify precisely where the mistake was.

Comment: Added the calculation

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I also discovered we can apply the same trick in numpy with `x.argsort().argsort()` but the idea is the same.